# What can I do if a package is not available on the newest version of Ubuntu (18.04) but is available on older versions?

Tags: apt, 18.04

I need to install libesd0-dev, but while it is available on earlier versions of Ubuntu from apt-get, it's not available for 18.04. Is there still a way for me to install it, or do I have to downgrade?

Comment: What specifically do you need it for?  Depending on what it was used for, you might be able to find an alternative solution, but typically you'd have to find a PPA for it, or try and install manually the Artful package but that's nontrivial.  (Note that this package was removed from Bionic and onwards because it is no longer maintained, see https://bugs.debian.org/894269 for details, as the parent package for that library package is `esound` and hasn't been updated in a decade)

Comment: I need it for building LineageOS roms for Android. It's listed as one of the required packages.

Comment: Does this post help? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1881944

Comment: @Jolt151 I would suggest that you *try* downloading the Artful packages for this, and then try and manually install them.  I'd also suggest you reach out to LineageOS and tell them that library is old, obsolete, and no longer in 'newer' Debian derivative OSes, and they should consider replacing the library with a better or newer one.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte - I went into my sources.list and uncommented the lines for xenial, then ran apt-get update and installing worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you put the xenial options in its own file in sources.list.d I think it will make sure that other aps default to the newest version and it will only use the old one when needed. now that you have enabled the xenial source, what happens when you try to do sudo apt upgrade? does it try to install a bunch of stuff?

Comment: No, I get 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. I guess that should present no problems then. Though I will add that uncommenting the lines for xenial significantly increases the time to run apt update and to search for the packages when you run apt install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to [Download it from here](https://pkgs.org/download/libesd0-dev) and install it with software center. This is what I would recommend.

Alternatively, if you need a bunch of older software, it is possible to add older repos to your apt list. If you want to install stuff from Artful when it's not available in Bionic you need to add its repo to your list.

If the library is available in Artful do the following:

First create a file in sources.list.d with your options:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artful.list
```

Add the following lines and save:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
```

Then update and install:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libesd0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to install using either of these options. My *sources.list* had no lines for xenial so I had to add them in manually. The deb packaged linked wouldn't install properly through action center or `sudo install (package name here).deb`.

The lines to add are:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
```

Found them through this [link](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

I'd like to add that I'm a relative newby to Ubuntu/Linux. So if there's any info that needs to be added or removed it's most certainly welcomed. Just trying to do my part. :)